# Using variable to define string.Format numeric format style

Tags: c#, string.format

I'd like to format a number using a run-time supplied format string.
Isn't something like this possible?

```
string.Format("{0:{1}}",0,"c")
```

The "c" may change to be any other type of format string.  I've tried various combinations but am failing to find the correct one.

Comment: you need a 2 step format. Step one to create the format string. Then step 2 to use that string in a second string.format to produce the final output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var s0 = string.Format("{{0:{0}}}", "c");
var s1 = string.Format(s0, 0);
```

The double `{` and `}` is to escape curly braces.

Comment: should that be var s0 = string.Format("{{0:{1}}}", 0, "c"); ?

Comment: This worked.  
    string.Format(string.Format("between {{0:{2}}} and {{1:{2}}}", lowerBound, upperBound, formatString), lowerBound, upperBound)